# Azure: delete Table using Azure REST API do not work when done as per documentation

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am following the Azure REST documentation for Table Storage: [Delete Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-table), [Create Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-table), [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services#table-service-shared-key-authentication). I am able to create the table only after dropping the "Content-Length" header which surprisingly is marked as required and including the "x-ms-version". This I could achieve after a few trial aand error for including the headers.

Similar issue I am facing for Delete. I am not able to delete the table using REST when strictly following the documentation. I tried a few trial and error but it did not help in delete case.

Below is the code snippet for create and delete table.

```
//Input your Storage Account and access-key associated to it.
const yourStorageAccountName = '';
const accessKeyStorageAccount = '';
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
const crypto = require("crypto");

async function createTable() {
    let now = new Date();
    let nowUTC = now.toUTCString();
    let contentType = "application/json";
    // construct input value
    let stringToSign = `POST\n\n${contentType}\n${nowUTC}\n/${yourStorageAccountName}/Tables`;
    let accesskey = accessKeyStorageAccount;
    // create base64 encoded signature
    let key = new Buffer(accesskey, "base64");
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key);
    hmac.update(stringToSign);
    let sig = hmac.digest("base64");
    console.log("SIGNATURE : " + sig);
    let args = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "SharedKey " + yourStorageAccountName + ":" + sig,
            "Content-Type": contentType,
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "x-ms-version": "2015-12-11",
            "Date": nowUTC,
            "DataServiceVersion": '3.0',
            "MaxDataServiceVersion": '3.0'
        },
        data: {
            "TableName": "fortwo"
        }
    };
    let restClient = new Client();
    restClient.post(`https://${yourStorageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/Tables`, args, function (data, response) {
        console.log(data);
        //console.log(response);
    });

}

async function deleteTable() {
    let now = new Date();
    let nowUTC = now.toUTCString();
    let contentType = "application/json"
    // construct input value
    let stringToSign = `DELETE\n\n${contentType}\n${nowUTC}\n/${yourStorageAccountName}/Tables(%27fourtwo%27)`;
    let accesskey = accessKeyStorageAccount;
    // create base64 encoded signature
    let key = new Buffer(accesskey, "base64");
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key);
    hmac.update(stringToSign);
    let sig = hmac.digest("base64");
    console.log("SIGNATURE : " + sig);
    console.log("nowutc : " + nowUTC);
    let args = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "SharedKey " + yourStorageAccountName + ":" + sig,
            "Content-Type": contentType,
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "Date": nowUTC,
            "x-ms-version": "2015-12-11",
            "DataServiceVersion": '3.0',
            "MaxDataServiceVersion": '3.0'
        }
    };
    let restClient = new Client();
    restClient.delete(`https://${yourStorageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/Tables('fourtwo')`, args, function (data, response) {
        console.log(data);
        //console.log(response);
    });
}

async function getTableAcl() {
    let now = new Date();
    let nowUTC = now.toUTCString();
    let contentType = "application/json"
    // construct input value
    let stringToSign = `GET\n\n\n${nowUTC}\n/${yourStorageAccountName}/goodwa\ncomp:acl`;
    let accesskey = accessKeyStorageAccount;
    // create base64 encoded signature
    let key = new Buffer(accesskey, "base64");
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key);
    hmac.update(stringToSign);
    let sig = hmac.digest("base64");
    console.log("SIGNATURE : " + sig);
    console.log("nowutc : " + nowUTC);
    let args = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "SharedKey " + yourStorageAccountName + ":" + sig,
            "Date": nowUTC,
            "x-ms-version": "2015-12-11"
        }
    };
    let restClient = new Client();
    restClient.get(`https://${yourStorageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/goodwa?comp=acl`, args, function (data, response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        //console.log(response);
    });
}


//createTable()
//deleteTable()
getTableAcl()
```

Same behaviour applies for [Get Table ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-acl) as well.

Am I missing something in both the cases?
I am okay with workaround I am using for create. Is there any workaround possible for Delete and [Get Table ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-acl) as well?

Attaching below the screen shot of delete request via Postman rest-client.
[image: Delete Table via Rest client.]

[image: Delete Table via Rest client with headers as suggested by Gaurav Mantri.]

[image: Delete Table via Rest client with different header combination.]

In above Rest calls I am using the signature calculated in the code snippet.

Comment: Can you please drop `Content-Type` header from both headers and inputValue as it is not required for delete operations. Next, please remove `Accept` header as well. Lastly, please check the error message returned by storage service. It will tell you the string it used for calculating authorization header. You can compare that with your inputValue. Both of them should match exactly.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but it did not help. In the error msg It did not mention the string it is using to calculate the signature at its end as it does in case of File/Queue.

I have added a screen shot of the combination of headers as suggested by you with error msg from azure in the question description. 

Just wanted to add that, "Content-Type" header is marked as required as per the azure documentation.

Comment: According to your screenshots there are double quotes around "mytab" in the URL. These should be single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot. Let me take a look. However, is there a particular reason you're not using Node SDK for Azure Storage and going directly for REST API? I am curious to know that.

Comment: @GauravMantri, yes we have specific requirement to use REST.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT regarding the screen shots and double quotes. I think I missed on that one. But even after including single quotes as well, there is no progress. And I am already running the code in which both have single quotes. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: Found the issue. Added answer with the correct code. I tried using it and I did not encounter any issues. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code is correct except for one minor thing (and I am sorry about telling you to remove content-type header). Essentially, in your `inputvalue`, the resource path should be url encoded. So your `inputvalue` should be:

```
let inputvalue = `DELETE\n\napplication/json\n${nowUTC}\n/${yourStorageAccountName}/Tables(%27mytab%27)`;
```

Escape `'` with `%27` i.e replace `'mytab'` with `%27mytab%27` and you should not get 403 error.

Here's the code that I used:

```
function deleteTable() {
    let now = new Date();
    let nowUTC = now.toUTCString();
    // construct input value
    let inputvalue = `DELETE\n\napplication/json\n${nowUTC}\n/${yourStorageAccountName}/Tables(%27mytab%27)`;
    console.log('inputvalue');
    console.log(inputvalue)
    let accesskey = accessKeyStorageAccount;
    // create base64 encoded signature
    let key = new Buffer(accesskey, "base64");
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key);
    hmac.update(inputvalue);
    let sig = hmac.digest("base64");
    console.log("SIGNATURE : " + sig);
    let args = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "SharedKey " + yourStorageAccountName + ":" + sig,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "x-ms-version": "2015-12-11",
            "x-ms-date": nowUTC,
            "DataServiceVersion": '3.0',
            "MaxDataServiceVersion": '3.0'
        }
    };
    let restClient = new Client();
    restClient.delete(`https://${yourStorageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/Tables('mytab')`, args, function (data, response) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    });
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Code works on my side. Also find that `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers are unnecessary unless we specify the `x-ms-version` with value `2015-12-11` or later, by default the empty content is recognized as atom feed and can be accepted. So using only `Authorization` and `x-ms-date` headers may also work.

Comment: @JerryLiu surprisingly(even when the dropped headers are marked required in azure documentation), your suggestion works. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @GauravMantri your fix works for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri, for GET operation on Table ACL, I am getting 403 error. The catch here is that there is no mention of Content-Type in Azure Table ACL documentation but in Authorization header part it is given to include Content-Type. Hence I am keeping the content-type as empty in "stringToSign" and am not providing the Content-Type header in the REST call. Code for this REST call is there in the code snippet of the question. Can you let me know of I am mising anything in this case?

Comment: Can you post this as a new question. Please include the code you’re using in the question. 403 errors are usually because of 3 reasons: 1) incorrect account key 2) time on client machine not set correctly and 3) improper string to sign (when using REST API instead of SDK).

Comment: I am not able to post question from this account. I will have my friend put up the Question. Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer to your question. HTH.